# The name "objectContainer" don't exist in current context | How initialize ObjectContainer in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I'm having a problem trying to run my automated tests with specflow. The error does not happen locally but when I try to upload the tests to TFS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VmXp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKh20.png)

I managed to simulate the error locally and it happens in the NUnit.Assembly file, the error is due to it saying that the "objectContainer" does not exist in the current context

[image: Error image]

I've tried several solutions but so far nothing seems to work, I'm sharing the file codes with you

General Hook

```
using BoDi;
using InternetBanking.Tests.Helpers;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace InternetBanking.Tests
{

    [Binding]
    public class HookGeral
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;
        public string _IBUITestsUri;
        public string _urlLogin;
        public string _urlLogout;
        public string _urlHome;
        public string _userName;
        public string _password;
        public string _newPassword;
        private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        private IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

        public string Browser { get; } = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Browser");
        public string IBUITestsUri { get; } = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IB- 
        uitests-uri")}";
        public string UrlLogin { get; } = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IB- 
        uitests-uri")}/usuario/login";
        public string UrlLogout { get; } = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IB- 
        uitests-uri")}/usuario/logout";
        public string UrlHome { get; } = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IB- 
        uitests-uri")}/home";
        public string UserName { get; } = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Username");
        public string Password { get; } = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Password");
        public string NewPassword { get; } = 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("NewPassword");
        public string Login { get; } = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Login");

        public HookGeral(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
            _objectContainer = objectContainer;
        }


        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            DefineBrowserDriver();
            _scenarioContext.Add("driver", _driver);
            _scenarioContext.Add("IB-uitests-uri", IBUITestsUri);
            _scenarioContext.Add("UrlLogin", UrlLogin);
            _scenarioContext.Add("UrlLogout", UrlLogout);
            _scenarioContext.Add("UrlHome", UrlHome);
            _scenarioContext.Add("Username", UserName);
            _scenarioContext.Add("Password", Password);
            _scenarioContext.Add("NewPassword", NewPassword);
            _scenarioContext.Add("Login", Login);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            try
            {
                string path = "C:\\IBNet-AutoTests-Pics\\";
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
                string sstitle = _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title.ToString();
                ss.SaveAsFile($"{path}{sstitle}.jpg", ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                IWebDriver driver = _objectContainer.Resolve<IWebDriver>();

                driver.Quit(); // Close the console app that was used to kick off the chrome 
            window
                driver.Dispose(); // Close the chromedriver.exe
            }
        }

        public class WebDriverController : IDisposable
        {
            public IWebDriver Driver;
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Driver.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void DefineBrowserDriver()
        {
            EBrowser browser;
            Enum.TryParse(Browser, true, out browser);
            switch (browser)
            {
                case EBrowser.IE:
                    _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    break;
                case EBrowser.Edge:
                    _driver = new EdgeDriver();
                    break;
                case EBrowser.Firefox:
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                default:

                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
                    options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                    options.AddArgument("--headless");
                    options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

                    _driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                    break;
            }
            _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(_driver);

        }

    }
}
```

StepsBase

```
using BoDi;
using InternetBanking.Tests.Helpers;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace InternetBanking.Tests.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public class StepsBase
    {
        public IWebDriver _driver;
        public string _IBUITestsUri;
        public string _urlLogin;
        public string _urlLogout;
        public string _urlHome;
        public string _userName;
        public string _password;
        public string _newPassword;
        public ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
        public IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

        public StepsBase(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;

            _driver = _scenarioContext["driver"] as IWebDriver;
            _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(_driver);
            _IBUITestsUri = _scenarioContext["IB-uitests-uri"] as string;
            _urlLogin = _scenarioContext["UrlLogin"] as string;
            _urlLogout = _scenarioContext["UrlLogout"] as string;
            _urlHome = _scenarioContext["UrlHome"] as string;
            _userName = _scenarioContext["Username"] as string;
            _password = _scenarioContext["Password"] as string;
            _newPassword = _scenarioContext["NewPassword"] as string;
            WDCustomFunctions.DefineDriver(_driver);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for all the help. Thank you

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. Copy and paste that into your question as plain text. Can you please add the full exception message and stack trace?

Comment: The StepsBase class constructor does not accept an IObjectContainer parameter, so `_objectContainer` is null.